# Audio streaming in C# to icecast2 (something like Edcast)

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, stream, icecast

I'm trying to create a program to stream audio from a microphone or stereo mixer to Icecast2 server, like Edcast.

I need show the way or a working example, how to do it. Ideally make it freeware or open source.

I do this in WPF form, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What server compatibility do you need?  If you just need Icecast 2.4 or later and compatible, you can use HTTP PUT which is a lot simpler and built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most sensible thing to do would be to wrap libshout for c#.
Looks like someone has done something like that before: http://wipsite.net/article/cs_cpp_interoperability/
I'd **strongly** recommend to use the latest version of libshout for such an exercise.

If you are interested to contribute fixes/updates to the windows build setup of libshout, I'd recommend to work with git head/master, as we've been changing some things recently.