# Creating an Audio broadcasting via shoutcast or icecast winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, shoutcast, icecast, broadcasting

I am in the process of creating an audio broadcasting app that will use either shoutcast or icecast (I need only one of them) and I can't seem to find any library that can help me out does any one have an Idea that can help me

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Icecast 2: protocol description, streaming to it using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215019/icecast-2-protocol-description-streaming-to-it-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible approaches that I can think of right now for C#:

- In an earlier answer I recommended to wrap the C library libShout: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29745771/2648865
- Someone seems to have done something like this:
  https://github.com/Zerpico/libShout-csharp 
  *Please note that the repository seems to contain DLL binaries, I strongly recommend against using random DLLs. Please consider compiling from sources.*

Comment: Thanks very much TBR that solved my problem and the Dll even though random they seem to work perfectly fine, although the only issue is that they are built to run on 32bit OS and I'm building it to target 64 bit because I wan't to listen to 64 bit processes that are running in the computer. I have no clue as to how I can convert them into a 64 dlls

Comment: Build from source, it's not that hard. There is no magic way to "convert" them otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a bit stupid here but where can I get the source from?